# Open phone dialer using a Android Xamarin WebView html link

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview

I'm trying to use the **ShouldOverrideUrlLoading()** method but the app crashes when I call it.

Below is my code:

```
private class HybridWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {


            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, string url)
            {

                var tel = "tel:";
                if (url.StartsWith(tel))
                {

                    var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url);
                    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial, uri);
                    var act = new Activity();
                    act.StartActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the following codes snippet:

```
var act = new Activity();
act.StartActivity(intent);
```

The method `StartActivity` should be called from current `context` instead of a new `Activity`. So you need to pass the current `context` to `HybridWebViewClient`:

```
public class HybridWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    Context context;
    public HybridWebViewClient(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
    {
        var tel = "tel:";
        if (url != null)
        {
            if (url.StartsWith(tel))
            {

                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url);
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial, uri);
                context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in the `OnCreate` method:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    ...
    webview.SetWebViewClient(new HybridWebViewClient(this));
    webview.LoadUrl("http://example.com");
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is in the craash dump? Is this related?

shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
This method was deprecated in API level 24. Use shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest) instead.